# SQL: Count items in each category

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT items.id, 
       items.category, 
       COUNT(*) 
  FROM items 
 GROUP BY items.id, 
          items.category
```

[image]
I want to display how many items in each category. 
For example,
category 1 - 6
category 2 - 7
category 3 - 4 ...
Please help me! I try this request and show me all the items with category :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT items.category, 
       COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM   items 
GROUP  BY items.category
```

Comment: It's nice to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

If, you want to display count based of category then use `group by` clause with colum `category`

```
SELECT category, count(*) as Noofitems
FROM items i
GROUP BY category;
```

Tiny word of advice :- Use table alise that could be easy to follow and read/wrire

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select items.category,COUNT(items.COUNT(*)) from items Group By items.category;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use 'distinct'

```
SELECT distinct items.category, 
       COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM   items 
GROUP  BY items.category
```

to get the correct count for each unique category